# I lose data in my serializer (django/angular)

Tags: django, angular

I have data in my front that I get from my serializer except that I lose two data "user" and "establishment".

```
const workplaceBody = {
  "user": this.currentUser.id,
  "establishment": response.body.id,
  "is_main_establishment": false
};
```

When I print validated_data in my serializer I only have one "is_main_establishment" data.

```
{'is_main_establishment': False}
```

I want to create a workplace linked to an establishment.

```
this.workplaceEstablishment.create(workplaceBody).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

My workplacesSerializer:

```
class WorkplacesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(source="establishment.id", read_only=True)
    name = CharField(source="establishment.name", read_only=True)
    type = CharField(source="establishment.type", read_only=True)
    selected = SerializerMethodField()

    def get_selected(self, instance):
        #print(instance)
        #print(self.context["request"].data)
        return (
            get_selected_establishment_id_from_request(self.context["request"])
            #"== instance.id
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        workplace = UserWorksAtEstablishment.objects.create(
            **validated_data, establishment_id=validated_data.establishment, user_id=validated_data.user
        )
        return workplace
    class Meta:
        model = UserWorksAtEstablishment
        fields = ("id", "name", "type", "is_main_establishment", "selected")
```

I don't see why I'm losing this data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It is not in your `fields`, nor in the fields you defined, so why do you expect it to be in the `validated_data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `user` and `establishment` are fields in your model for the table, and then you can add them to your serializer by doing:

```
class Meta:
    model = UserWorksAtEstablishment
    fields = ("id", "user", "establishment", "name", "type", "is_main_establishment", "selected")
```

Or just add all the fields:

```
    class Meta:
        model = UserWorksAtEstablishment
        fields = '__all__'
```